# Verwendung von "der" statt "er" in einem Zeitungsartikel

Tags: word-usage, pronoun

Dieser Absatz kommt aus dem Spiegel ([Link](https://www.spiegel.de/ausland/iran-recep-tayyip-erdogan-laesst-wladimir-putin-warten-und-fordert-dann-seine-unterstuetzung-in-syrien-a-476d6241-4286-4867-8a7d-5a6d9fcdeb0a)):

> Für den Gipfel in Teheran verließ Kremlchef Putin eigens das erste Mal
> seit Beginn seines Krieges gegen die Ukraine den postsowjetischen
> Raum. Vor Ort musste er dann trotzdem erst mal warten – auf den
> türkischen Präsidenten. **Der** ließ sich betont viel Zeit, ehe er zum
> Händeschütteln mit ihm vor die Kameras der Weltpresse trat.

Gibt es einen besonderen Grund dafür, dass der Autor dieses Artikels das fettgedruckte "der" statt "er" benutzt hat? Bei "der" ist es klarer, dass das Subjekt des Satzes türkischer Präsident Erdogan ist (also der im vorherigen Satz letzte erwähnte Person)? Ich hatte gedacht, dass "der" normalerweise in der Umgangssprache benutzen würde, aber ich vermute, dass dieses "der" nicht so benutzt wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Bei "der" ist es klarer, dass das Subjekt des Satzes Putin ist (also der im vorherigen Satz letzte erwähnte Person)?

Das Subjekt des Satzes ist eben nicht Putin, und genau das ist der Grund für die Verwendung von "der" ;) Denn die zuletzt erwähnte Person ist der türkische Präsident. "Der" wird hier demonstrativ verwendet, um zu verdeutlichen, dass mit "er" ab sofort jemand anderes gemeint ist bisher - eben Erdogan statt Putin.

Comment: Ach danke, ich habe Putin und Erdogan verwechselt, während ich meine Frage geschrieben habe. Das habe ich repariert.

Comment: Gibt es aber einen Grund dafür, warum "der" statt "dieser" im Artikel steht? Wäre "dieser" nicht formeller bzw. passender?

Comment: @cruthers Das folgende ist mein Sprachempfinden und nicht zwingend allgemeingültig. Aber in diesem Fall wirkt "dieser" auf mich stärker demonstrativ als "der". Man könnte sagen, der bildliche Zeigerfinger ist größer bei "Dieser ließ sich betont viel Zeit" im Vergleich zu "Der ließ sich betont viel Zeit". Oder anders formuliert, es ist der Unterschied zwischen "der da" und "DIESER DA". An dieser Stelle wäre das meiner Meinung nach unnötig drastisch und würde implizit die Frage aufwerfen, was der Autor damit ausdrücken wollte.

Comment: Ok, danke - und wenn man diese Sätze vorlesen würde, würde man das "der" betonen?

Comment: @cruthers Ja, das "der" würde man betonen, allerdings nicht sehr. Die Idee ist so ähnlich wie bei "der" oder "dieser" - mit "dieser" wäre auch die Betonung stärker.

Comment: You could also say (or write) _Letzterer ließ sich viel Zeit_. or _Der nämlich ließ sich betont viel Zeit, ..._

Answer (score 0):

Das "der" ist hier stellvertretend für bzw. gleichbedeutend mit "dieser" und tatsächlich, wie @HenningKockerbeck schreibt, ein Demonstrativpronomen.